# NPM is not compatible with node 8.x

Tags: node.js, npm, frontend

I know that version node 8.x is very old but I need works with project of this version on node. I installed a few version node 8.x with this website https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ . As you know npm is installed together with node so everything should be ok, I thought. But in my case which I tryed type `npm install` or `npm --version`, etc. npm returned error that node version is so old I shoud install newer which is not an option. Any ideas how can I use nodejs 8.x with npm?

Comment: Try using `nvm` it will change the versions for you

Comment: Node 8 has been a dead version for many, many years now. The current version is 18, the current LTS is 16, and the oldest "technically still supported" version is 14. While you can (and should) use `nvm`  to manage multiple node versions on the same machine or user account, you should _not_ use Node 8, for the same reason you should not use PHP 4 or Python 2: it's been out of support, and as a consequence has been a security liability, for years now.